# How to find data inside one cell with line breaks using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with some data, the Column B have names of clients and the Column D have stored Serial Numbers of equipments, if one client have more then one equipment, I just put a line break and keep adding S/N, to me it was the easy way to go at the time, but now I'm working on another sheet in the same workbook and want to pull the Name of the client when I type the Serial Number, if the client has only one equipent, the code works fine, but when try to search a serial number that is stored together in the same cell it give me an error "Run-time error'13': Type mismatch".

This is what I have so far..
[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If Me.listadeinv.Value <> "" Then
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Monitoramento")
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clientes")
    Dim i2 As Integer

    i = Application.Match(VBA.CVar(Me.listadeinv.Value), sh2.Range("D:D"), 0)

    Me.nome.Caption = sh2.Range("B" & i).Value

End If


End Sub
```

The only workarround I found by myself was create a new sheet, put every Serial Number there in single cells and use this code to find the owner of the equipment, this is exacly what I want to do, but using VBA code.

```
=VLOOKUP(" * " & B1 & " * " ; CHOOSE({1\2}; Clientes!$D$2:$D$497; Clientes!$B$2:$B$497); 2; 0)
```

Comment: please provide some sample input and expected output as well

Comment: Could you give an example of "serial number that is stored together in the same cell"?

Comment: Sure, if look for "ST20K17001024" witch is alone in one cell it comes back "3J Moveis" the owner of the product.
But if I try this one "154E51199190085" witch is stored in same cell with another it give the error,in this exemple it is stored like this <br> meaning line break. "154E51199190085 <br>154AC1198210323".

Comment: I have added a image with a demo of what I have so far, the column D  has Text format, since some of the S/N are to long to be stored in Number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following if it works:

```
' do not use Integer for row variables, values are limited to -32,768 to 32,767 
Dim i As Long

' wrap with asterisk your serial number for partial match, I use cast it to String instead of variant
strSerialNum = "*" & Cstr(Me.listadeinv.Value) & "*"

' variable "i" may now accept values more than 32,767,  
i = Application.Match(strSerialNum, sh2.Range("D:D"), 0)
```